# Using Machine Learning for generating Query Execution Plan

Tags: query-optimization, sql-execution-plan

I am aware of cost based and rule based optimizers ? Are there any Query engines that use Machine Learning (based on similar queries run in the past) for generating Query execution plans ?

Comment: It depends on what you call Machine Learning. As in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning, ML involves an algorithm that automatically improves through experience and data use. All major DBs engines through stats do that, someway. They keep a tally on how data is growing and queried, and how the memory, CPU, and disks behave, adjusting the **Query Plans**. I found some interesting articles on other approaches via Google: https://www.google.com/search?q=ml+for+query+optimization

Comment: It doesn't take ML to know that `WHERE DATE(col) = '2022-01-10'` is transformable to the [sargable](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/28838/sargeable) expression `WHERE col >= '2022-01-10' AND col < '2022-01-11'`.  Please :-) don't distract the really great engineers working on query planning with shiny things to chase! :-)